# How can I make this table look nicer?

Tags: tables, color, colortbl

I am new to LaTeX and am trying to make a nice table. However, the best I can get is this:
[image]

Does anybody have any improvements i can make?

MWE:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{D7D7D7} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D7D7D7}\textit{\textbf{Curve Color}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{ c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D7D7D7}\textit{\textbf{Time of Descent (s)}}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{ c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D7D7D7}\textit{\textbf{Length of Curve (m)}}} \\ \hline
Red     & 0.6390  & 1.414   \\ \hline
Yellow  & 0.5588  & 1.4534  \\ \hline
Blue    & 0.5486  & 1.5206  \\ \hline
Purple  & 0.4835  & 1.4831  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Have a look at the booktabs documentation, it has a lot of useful advice about professional looking tables https://texdoc.org/serve/booktabs.pdf/0

Comment: Okay, I have taken a look but I am not too sure where and how to apply it to the code, do you know any youtube videos or something else where it is easier to see where goes where?

Comment: The documentation also has examples, for example on p.5

Comment: also don't do `[h!]` (it usually generates a warning that it is being changed)  `h` on its own gives latex very little chance to place the table, and `!` should only be used sparingly as it means "ignore the user-set constraints in this one table" and it doesn't make sense to always ignore the constraints/

Comment: I am not too big a fan of how the table looks even using the suggestions on the booktabs doc. Do you have any other possible improvements?

Comment: Okay, I won't use h!

Comment: Someone pls help

Comment: @Mathsimprover, instead of complaining in comments, which will be flagged for you soon, it's better to rework your question a little and let us know there, what you are after: i.e. what your specification is AND what hinders you to make progress. The way it's now, without having tested your code, is quite MS-Wordish ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest (a) getting rid of all vertical rules, (b) using fewer, but well-spaced horizontal rules, (c) providing more hierarchical structure to the header material, and (d) aligning the numbers in the data columns on the decimal point markers. Aside: coloring, bolding, and italicizing the header row does *not* magically improve either the legibility or the readability of a table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule macros
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type and '\unit' macro
  
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{2}{S[table-format=1.4]} @{}}
\toprule 
Curve  & {Time of Descent}  & {Length of Curve} \\
Color  & {(\unit{\second})} & {(\unit{\meter})} \\ 
\midrule
Red     & 0.6390  & 1.414   \\ 
Yellow  & 0.5588  & 1.4534  \\ 
Blue    & 0.5486  & 1.5206  \\ 
Purple  & 0.4835  & 1.4831  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```